# GetDateTimeString returns a string - why do I get a Type Mismatch when assigning the output to a variable?

Tags: inno-setup, type-mismatch

When attempting to compile the following code I get a "Type Mismatch" referencing the line containing GetDateTimeString.  This function is supposed to output a string (according to Inno Setup Help) and I'm attempting to assign the output to a variable of type string.... Why am I getting a Type Mismatch?

```
{ Compile the string for the Beveled Text label }
function get_bev_label(Param: String) : String;
var 
datetime : String;
begin
  datetime :=  GetDateTimeString ('mmmm/d/yyyy', '', '');
  result := ('Build Date ' + datetime + ' - All Rights Reserved');
end;
```

Comment: Because you must specify a `Char` for the `DateSeparator` and `TimeSeparator` parameters. Empty string `''` is not a valid char, hence the type mismatch.

Comment: E.g. `GetDateTimeString ('mmmm/d/yyyy', #0, #0)`

Comment: @RobeN thank you! I was tearing my hair out here...

Comment: @TLama why not post it as an answer?